# How to recover an email address from an application of MD5 hash function?

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

First, we generated a series of string prefixes with lengths increasing by 2. For example, if our secret email address was `helloworld@company.com`, we would generate:

> he
>
> hell
>
> hellow
>
> hellowor
>
> ...
>
> helloworld@ company.com

Then, for every prefix s, we computed the following hash J:

md5(md5(e) + s + md5(s))    [where + is the string concatenation operator and e=xyz@gmail.com is YOUR email address(Of course known!)].

Finally, we concatenated all hash strings J to form the long hash above!

For example, for helloworld@ company.com,

we would compute:

```
md5(md5(' xyz@gmail.com') + 'he' + md5('he')) + 

md5(md5(' xyz@gmail.com') + 'hell' + md5('hell')) + 

md5(md5(' xyz@gmail.com') + 'hellow' + md5('hellow')) + 

...
```

For the sake of simplicity, you can assume that our email address only contains alphanumeric characters and these 4 characters: _.@+

the long hash:

> 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

Also, let's assume we know the domain "@company.com".How to figure out the email address for the above given condition?

Comment: Which email address would you try to recover in this case? The secret one used to concatenate or the one known as 'e'?

Comment: secret one email address

Comment: what maskes you assume that thing ?

Comment: what makes you assume that thing ? It says that the COMPANY's email address has been split as 'he'and you apply the given md5 condition .Now append another next two chars to "he" and it becomes "helo".Again apply the given md5 condition on this string.Continue the process till the end of the company's email address.The long hash is generated after concatenating all the hashes you get.

Answer (score 2):

Most MD5 cracking is done through the use of rainbow tables. However most don't go nearly up to 32 characters. Since you are doing md5 on yet another md5, it won't be subject to other dictionary attacks. So it is very unlikely that anyone could crack it back to the original.

I'm not sure why there is a growing appending of the hash. Won't an attacker take the last 32 characters of the hash and crack that one since it is the only one that contains the full secret email address?

If you are the one trying to build this algorithm, I suggest you instead use a well supported symmetric encryption library with the secret email being the password. It is never a good idea to build your own.

You also might want to ask on the security site: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is just a task given to me.I really don't have any idea as to how to go about working on it.Please help!!

Comment: Linux :                                                           I tried the steps mentioned here    http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/rainbow-tables-create-use-them-crack-passwords-0131470/ but ./configure command fails "No such file or directory"